# Background Error fault when applying condition

Tags: javascript, html

So `if x = Number value background` changes fine, my question is when x has no value. How can I have a `background-color` of  `#ffffff`. Currently, code is defaulting to `#db0000`.

[image: Snip of HTML code]

JS:

```js
var grid_value = document.getElementById("Vone").innerHTML;
var x = grid_value;
            
if (x >= 0 && x < 15) {
  document.getElementById("GridA").style.backgroundColor = "#db0000";
} else if (x >= 15 && x < 25) {
  document.getElementById("GridA").style.backgroundColor = "#f0ad4e";
} else if (x >= 25) {
  document.getElementById("GridA").style.backgroundColor = "#5cb85c";
} else if (x = "Pick" ) {
  document.getElementById("GridA").style.backgroundColor = "#0085eb";
} else if (x = "" ) {
  document.getElementById("GridA").style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you tried - for example using console.log in your browser's dev tools facility to see exactly what value you are getting. Also note that where you have an if test you need to use == rather than = (a single = is an assignment).

Comment: do it this way, else if(!x), this way both null, undefined can be managed

Comment: There are a few issues here. First, your question has nothing to do with CSS. The code you provided is not CSS. It is JavaScript! Then you get the `innerHTML` which will always return a string and not an Integer. You have to convert the String as an Integer first. Then instead of using `var name = element; var x = name` you could also use `x = element` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here you haven't given any conditions if x doesn't have a value, so the default condition is x=0.
You should try else if (!x).

```
else if (!x) {
  document.getElementById("GridA").style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
}
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const gA = document.getElementById("GridA");
document.getElementById("Vone").addEventListener("blur", function(event){
  gA.classList = "";
  var x = this.value;
  if  (x === "") {
    gA.classList.add("white");
  } else if (x === "Pick") {
    gA.classList.add("color1");
  } else if (x >= 0 && x < 15) {
    gA.classList.add("color2");
  } else if (x >= 15 && x < 25) {
    gA.classList.add("color3");
  } else if (x >= 25) {
    gA.classList.add("color4");
  } 
});
```

```css
#GridA { height:100px; border:1px solid grey; margin-top:5px; }

.color1 { background-color:#dbf000; }
.color2 { background-color:#f0ad4e; }
.color3 { background-color:#5cb85c; }
.color4 { background-color:#0085eb; }
.white  { background-color:#ffffff; }
```

```html
<input id="Vone">
<div id="GridA"></div>
```